How to make button in media player work in winui3
I have these lines to handle event when user click the button in the control of media player
mp.MediaPlayer.CommandManager.PreviousReceived += CommandManager_PreviousReceived;
mp.MediaPlayer.CommandManager.FastForwardReceived += CommandManager_FastForwardReceived;
mp.MediaPlayer.CommandManager.RewindReceived += CommandManager_RewindReceived;

These are the process functions:
private void CommandManager_NextReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender ,
        MediaPlaybackCommandManagerNextReceivedEventArgs args) {
    DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => {
        args.Handled = true;
        PlayNextInQueue();
    });
}

private void CommandManager_PreviousReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender ,
        MediaPlaybackCommandManagerPreviousReceivedEventArgs args) {
    DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => {
        args.Handled = true;
        PlayPreviousInQueue();
    });
}

private void CommandManager_FastForwardReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender ,
        MediaPlaybackCommandManagerFastForwardReceivedEventArgs args) {
    args.Handled = true;
    if ((mp.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.TotalSeconds - mp.MediaPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds) <= 5) {
        PlayNextInQueue();
    }
    else {
        mp.MediaPlayer.Position += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    }
}

private void CommandManager_RewindReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender ,
     MediaPlaybackCommandManagerRewindReceivedEventArgs args) {
    DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => {
        args.Handled = true;
        if (mp.MediaPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds > 5) {
            mp.MediaPlayer.Position -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        }
        else {
            mp.MediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
    });
}

When I test the button the fast forward button is the only working button, the rewind can click but only once and after that it does nothing when I press it again, the next and previous do not do anything when pressed. Also when I add a breakpoint to all these functions the CommandManager_FastForwardReceived is the only function hitting a breakpoint when clicked and the rest of it are not.
after some research and trying I met new error :
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll

I don't know how to fix this.
Project link for more detail : github

MediaPlayer.CommandManager.FastForwardReceived and MediaPlayer.CommandManager.RewindReceived work for me. For NextReceived and PreviousReceived to work, you may Play a list of media items with MediaPlaybackList.

Did you fix your issue?

@AndrewKeepCoding i met new issue , can you help me ?

@tribeti you can edit your question and update the project.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT i already done that

This works for me. I tested in a new project.
XAML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="App1.BlankWindow4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">AAA</Button>
        <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                <MediaTransportControls IsCompact="False"                       IsNextTrackButtonVisible="True"
                            IsPreviousTrackButtonVisible="True"     IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True"
                            IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True"        IsRepeatButtonVisible="True"
                            IsFastForwardEnabled="True"             IsFastRewindEnabled="True"/>
            </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        </MediaPlayerElement>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

Codebehind:
MediaPlaybackList _mediaPlaybackList;
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _mediaPlaybackList = new MediaPlaybackList();

    // init
    var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    var hwnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
    WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(openPicker, hwnd);

    // cách hiển thị và vị trí file mặc định
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;

    // các định dạng file cho phép
    string[] fileTypes = [".wmv", ".mp4", ".mkv", ".mp3", ".flac"];

    // thêm các định dạng file cho phép
    foreach (string fileType in fileTypes)
    {
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileType);
    }

    var files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file));
        _mediaPlaybackList.Items.Add(mediaPlaybackItem);
    }

    _mediaPlaybackList.MaxPlayedItemsToKeepOpen = 3;

    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    _mediaPlayer.Source = _mediaPlaybackList;
    _mediaPlayer.CommandManager.NextReceived += CommandManager_NextReceived;
    _mediaPlayer.CommandManager.PreviousReceived += CommandManager_PreviousReceived;
    _mediaPlayer.CommandManager.FastForwardReceived += CommandManager_FastForwardReceived;
    _mediaPlayer.CommandManager.RewindReceived += CommandManager_RewindReceived;

    mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(_mediaPlayer);
}

private void CommandManager_NextReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender, MediaPlaybackCommandManagerNextReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void CommandManager_PreviousReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender, MediaPlaybackCommandManagerPreviousReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void CommandManager_FastForwardReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender, MediaPlaybackCommandManagerFastForwardReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void CommandManager_RewindReceived(MediaPlaybackCommandManager sender, MediaPlaybackCommandManagerRewindReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}


sorry for reply this late but it not work for me :(

@tribeti have you tried it in a new WinUI3 project?

no i didn't, i added changed into current project

@tribeti you may try it to narrow down your issue.
